# SVG apply same transform-origin to all children of a group/symbol

Tags: css, svg

I can't get reusable items or all children of a group to conform to a specified `transform-origin`. The goal is to be able to reuse the same shape over and over with the same template of style. However, considering `transform-origin` the styling, CSS or otherwise, does not cascade. It will only apply at time of `<use>`.

For example:

```css
svg {
  width: 125px; height: 125px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
  <defs>
    <ellipse id="svg-ellipse-def" cx="500" cy="500" rx="140" ry="455" transform-origin="center" style="transform-origin: center"/>
  </defs>
  
  <symbol id="svg-ellipse" >
    <ellipse cx="500" cy="500" rx="140" ry="455" transform-origin="center" style="transform-origin: center"/>
  </symbol>
    
  <g fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="50">
     <use xlink:href="#svg-ellipse"/>
     <use xlink:href="#svg-ellipse" transform="rotate(45)"/>
     <use xlink:href="#svg-ellipse" transform="rotate(90)"/>
     <use xlink:href="#svg-ellipse-def" transform="rotate(-45)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Essentially, the transform origin doesn't apply regardless if I use `class=` attribute or `transform-origin=` property or even inline style. I've also tried wrapping it in a `<defs>` container.

Desired outcome:

```
<use xlink:href="#svg-ellipse" transform="rotate(45)"/>     
<use xlink:href="#svg-ellipse" transform="rotate(90)"/>
<use xlink:href="#svg-ellipse" transform="rotate(-45)"/>
```

But right now it looks like this:

```
<use xlink:href="#svg-ellipse" transform="rotate(45)" style="transform-origin:center"/>     
<use xlink:href="#svg-ellipse" transform="rotate(90)" style="transform-origin:center"/>
<use xlink:href="#svg-ellipse" transform="rotate(-45)" style="transform-origin:center"/>
```

```css
svg {
  width: 125px; height: 125px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
  
  <symbol id="svg-ellipse" >
    <ellipse cx="500" cy="500" rx="140" ry="455"/>
  </symbol>
    
  <g fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="50">
     <use xlink:href="#svg-ellipse"/>
     <use xlink:href="#svg-ellipse" transform="rotate(45)"  transform-origin="center"/>
     <use xlink:href="#svg-ellipse" transform="rotate(90)" transform-origin="center"/>
     <use xlink:href="#svg-ellipse" transform="rotate(-45)"  transform-origin="center"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

---

According to the [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement):

If the ‘use’ element references a ‘symbol’ element:

> In the generated content, the ‘use’ will be replaced by ‘g’, where all attributes from the ‘use’ element except for ‘x’, ‘y’, ‘width’, ‘height’ and ‘xlink:href’ are transferred to the generated ‘g’ element. An additional transformation translate(x,y) is appended to the end (i.e., right-side) of the ‘transform’ attribute on the generated ‘g’, where x and y represent the values of the ‘x’ and ‘y’ attributes on the ‘use’ element. The referenced ‘symbol’ and its contents are deep-cloned into the generated tree, with the exception that the ‘symbol’ is replaced by an ‘svg’.

Looking at the dev console, this is confirmed, and the style is applied inline but not honored:

[image]

Even if the `<use>` element has an inline styling of `transform-origin`, because the symbol now is converted to it's own SVG as a child of the `<use>` element, and it has it's own inline styling, shouldn't that take higher priority over it's parent's inline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target the `<use>` element itself, but none of its content. The content can, in principle, *inherit* CSS properties. But the barrier you'll always run into is: neither the CSS [transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-property) nor the [transform-origin](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-origin-property) property are inheritable.

- If you rotate the `<use>` element, you rotate it around the tranform origin of the `<use>` element, while the contents of the shadow DOM stay in place relative to its root.
- If you set a transform-origin for the `<symbol>` or `<ellipse>`, it will only be applied if you transform that itself, and the transformation will be cloned into each of its reuses.

The best solution I see is giving all use elements that reference the same symbol the same transform-origin. For the attribute selector to work, you'll need to leave off the `xlink` namespace. That is deprecated anyway, but you'll have to consider [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/href#Browser_compatibility).

But then, the same is true for [transform-origin support in SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin#Browser_compatibility). That, by the way is the reason for
setting `transform-box: fill-box`. After there were some differences in implementation between Firefox and Chrome, it is now accepted that this
property is needed for SVG elements to transform them in relation to their bounding box. I've changed your example a bit to demonstrate.

```css
svg {
  width: 125px; height: 125px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

use[href="#symbol1"] {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1500 1500">
  
  <symbol id="symbol1" >
    <ellipse cx="500" cy="500" rx="140" ry="455" />
  </symbol>
    
  <g fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="50">
     <use href="#symbol1" transform="translate(200, 400)" />
     <use href="#symbol1" transform="translate(200, 400) rotate(45)"/>
     <use href="#symbol1" transform="translate(200, 400) rotate(90)"/>
     <use href="#symbol1" transform="translate(200, 400) rotate(-45)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: fyi, my first snippet is not desired output, the second snippet is (the one that's collapsed), but that's neither here nor there, I just didn't want future question seekers to be confused. I was aware of transform-box and saw it will researching other answers and don't want to risk using it. Naturally I'm trying to reach as many end users possible and the working draft was only submitted last november for that. I guess I'll just stick to the three length syntax of rotate `rotate(angle, cx, cy)` but I fear this will complicate animations as some of the dimensions will be dynamic.

Comment: The example is reacting strange: on Firefox, the desired result is shown immediately, but on Chrome, it is not after initial rendering. But if you open dev tools there and deactivate one of the rules for the use selector, and then activate it again, the elements will snap into the desired positions. That is a bewildering bug.

Comment: interesting. I see what you mean. Might be a stackoverflow `iframe` setting, or lack thereof

Comment: Nope, happens also for standalone SVG file.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=697052, apparently

Comment: 3 length rotate syntax it is. That's dated over a year ago :(